# Converting videos to single codec format

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I simply want to convert videos, any video codec format(ex: HEVC, MPEG4) to AVC(H.264/x264) .mp4 container with audio codec AAC.

I don't want to resize (scale) the video, I don't want to change its aspect ratio and I don't want it to lose quality.

All I want is "to change any codec format to single standardized video & audio codec format", that's all.

Reason: my DVD player won't recognize any formats other than AVC .mp4. So, how do I do that using `ffmpeg` or any other command line tools/systemd service which can utilize hardware acceleration?

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu, but is easy. You search for `ffmpeg h264`, click the top link https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264, and follow the steps.

Comment: Can you point me to any other stack exchange forum where it makes more sense to ask this question? I see several questions in this forum related to usage of ffmpeg :)